# Angularfire2 firestore - document "string slash" notation

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

Information around referencing documents with this "string slash" notation is a little sparse. Here is an example provided in [the docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md):

```
constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.userDoc = afs.doc<Item>('user/david');
    ...
}
```

I can tell it's referencing the `user` collection and getting a doc with a unique id `david`. But how can I determine the field for the unique index (in this case `david`) that firestore looks up in that string-slash notation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realize that the ID is implicitly set when you use `doc()` and `set()` in this way. In this case, `david` was supplied as the id:

```
this.afs.doc(`user/david`).set(userObject);
```

So once you *add* it like that, it can be recalled by the ID you set. Calling that method over will replace (or "destructively set", as the docs note) what is stored under that ID.

Answer (score 2):

David here!

1 + 2) Think of `david` as the primary key in the `users` collection.

3) You use a generated ID when you can ID is not important and you can get back the document with a query.

```
constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore): {
  const shirtsCollection = afs.collection<Item>('tshirts', ref => {
    return ref.where('price', '==', 10.00);
  });
  this.shirtsUnder10$ = shirtsCollection.valueChanges();
}
```

In some less common cases you an also create a lookup collection. Where you have one known id that contains a list of generated ids. This is useful for situations like "event attendees". If you know the ID of the event, you can get back a list of attendees IDs for the users who attended the event.

Comment: Thanks David! But you didn't really the first 2 questions - which field is `david` and how was it specified as the field to use in the string-slash getter?

Comment: When I try to query by `'someCollection/arbitraryField'` it doesn't work. How were you able to look up a doc by an arbitrary field? That's really the heart of my question. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really make my question very clear. I figured it out.  Tried to clarify it a bit for whoever comes across it.